# QueueClient Class alternatives

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Microsoft has deprecated the package named Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus and updated the package as Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus but in the recent update they have removed the QueueClient class. So what is the alternative for this QueueClient class.

```
public IQueueClient GetQueueClient(string queueName)
{
    return new QueueClient(ConnectionString.Trim('"'), queueName);
}
```

Comment: What operations you were doing with the `QueueClient` in the previous SDK?

Comment: To receive the message and making connection with queue using QueueClient.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/MigrationGuide.md#receiving-messages

Answer (score 4):

In the new version you do the same thing with two classes `ServiceBusClient` and`serviceBusSender`. After you install `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` you need to update `QueueClient` with its alternative as below:

```
public ServiceBusSender PutintoQueueClient(string queueName)
{
    var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(ConnectionString.Trim('"'));
    return serviceBusClient.CreateSender(queueName)
}
```

Now you can send your messages into Queue like

```
var serviceBusSender = PutintoQueueClient(queueName);
await serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

For receiving Messages it will be like

```
public ServiceBusReceiver GetQueueClient(string queueName)
{
    var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(ConnectionString.Trim('"'));
    return serviceBusClient.CreateReceiver(queueName)
}
```

Now you can send your messages into Queue like

```
var serviceBusSender = GetQueueClient(queueName);
ServiceBusReceivedMessage receivedMessage = await 
serviceBusSender.ReceiveMessageAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Reference:
 [Guide for migrating to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus from Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/MigrationGuide.md#receiving-messages)